# Iranian University Math Competition (2023) (first day, Question 4)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, contest-math

I am trying to solve the following problem, but was not able to solve yet. All I can show so far is the order of $a$ is odd.

(This is from Iranian university math competition. I put it here for those who are interested. Also, I will translate and put other question.)

Let $G$ be a finite group. Suppose there exists $a \in G$ and a function $f : G \longrightarrow G$ such that for all $x\in G$
$$ f(xa) = xf(x) $$
Prove that the order of $G$ is an odd number.

Comment: Is $f(xa)=xf(x)$ correct? Shouldn't there be an $a$ on the right hand side of the equation?

Comment: @JohnDouma $f(ax)=af(x)$ holds for many goups of even order (for example taking $a=1$ and $f$ any map).

Comment: Where can I find more of the questions from this exam?

Comment: @TheBestMagician The website of Iranian Math Society is a good source.

Comment: @TheBestMagician Here is another question from this Exam: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4738373/max-number-of-primes-among-quotients-of-natural-numbers?noredirect=1#comment10050796_4738373

Comment: You may have the good intention of translating these problems into English for us, but unfortunately we cannot allow questions that do not have sufficient context (e.g. your effort in finding an answer). To avoid question closure for this reason, please include your own attempt in subsequent questions, or if you have a complete solution (and the problem is sufficiently interesting) then you can indicate it in the question and post your solution as an answer simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If $a = e$ (the neutral element), then it clearly follows from the function relation that $x = e \forall x \in G$. Thus, $G$ is the trivial group which has odd order.

We now show that indeed $a = e$ is the case.

Assume to the contrary that $a \neq e$. Therefore, $|G| \geq 2$.

$x \rightarrow e$ in the given yields: $f(a) = ef(e) = f(e)$.

$x \rightarrow a$ in the given yields: $f(a^2) = f(aa) = af(a) = af(e)$

It is easy to show inductively that $f(a^n) = a^{n-1}f(e)$ must hold for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Since $G$ is finite, $a$ will have a finite order $k$. Furthermore, by our assumption, it must be that $k > 1$ (otherwise $a = e$).

Then, it follows that:

$f(a^k) = a^{k-1}f(e) \overset{a^k = e}{\iff} f(e) = a^{k-1}f(e) \iff a^{k-1} = e$.

As $k-1 \neq 0$, the minimality of the order $k$ of $a$ is contradicted. Hence, it must be that $a = e$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Please explain why OP's question is not a good question.

Comment: @IraeVid Please read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This answer is wrong, because the "easy to show" induction does not work. Rather one has $f(a^n) = a^{n(n-1)/2} f(e)$, and this really does define a solution for $G = C_3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let order of $a$ be $n$, We have $f(e)=f(a^n)=a^{n-1}f(a^{n-1})=\dots=a^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}f(e)$. Hence $n|\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. So $n$ is odd.

Now if $G$ has even order, let $t$ be an element of order 2, we have $f(t)=f(ta^n)=ta^{n-1}f(ta^{n-1})=\dots=\prod_{i=1}^{n} ta^{n-i}f(t)$. Thus $\prod_{i=1}^{n} ta^{n-i}=e$. (You can actrually prove that if $\prod_{i=1}^{n} ta^{n-i}=e$ for every $t$, then such $f$ exists.)

Then we use the "rotation property" to cancel out some terms in the product: if $ab\cdots yz=1$, then $b\cdots yza=1$. The product is $ta^{n-1}\cdots tat$. Rotate the last $at$ to first we got $ta^{n-2}\cdots ta^2t$, Then we can rotate the last $a^2t$, do this iteratively we have only the central $t$ left. Thus $t=e$, which is contradictary

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.