# Max Number of primes among quotients of natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The following question is from Iranian Math Contest for University Students (2023). The problem posed as a “Number Theory Problem” but I think it has nothing to do with number theory. In fact the main reason I posted the problem here is to see if anyone can come up with a number theory solution or not.

Suppose $a_1,… , a_n$ are distinct natural numbers. Show that among numbers $\frac{a_i}{a_j}$ there are at most $n-1$ distinct prime numbers.

Comment: The problem looks interesting but without some context (your attempt to solve the problem, for example), it will be probably closed.

Comment: This is not true. Take 4 numbers: 2, 6, 10 and 30. There are 4 rationals made from them that are prime: 6/2, 10/2, 30/6 and 30/10.

Comment: @Saša Thank you for your comment. It was my mistake, the correct form is “distinct prime numbers”.I have corrected the question.

Comment: What is the source of this question, please?

Comment: This *might* work. Consider the graph with one vertex for each $a_i$ and an edge joining $a_i$ and $a_j$ if either $a_i/a_j$ or $a_j/a_i$ is a prime. Show that there can't be a cycle involving distinct primes (that's the hard part). Then the graph must be a tree, or a forest, and have at most $n-1$ edges.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is from Iranian Math Contest for University Students (2023).  The problem posed as a “Number Theory Problem” but I think it has nothing to do with number theory. In fact the main reason I posted the problem here is to see if anyone can come up with a number theory solution or not.

Comment: All of that information should have been included in the body of the question when you posted it, Sara. That might have been enough to prevent its closure, and it might be enough to get it reopened, if you add it to the question now. As long as it is closed, no one is able to post an answer, and the question runs the risk of being deleted. And when your questions get deleted, you run the risk of being banned from asking more questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited the question.

Comment: I haven't worked this through, but it may be an approach: Arrange the $a_i$ in increasing order. Then $a_1$ is not divisible by any other $a_i$. $a_2$ can only be divisible by $a_1$ (but need not be), and if there is an integer quotient and it is prime, then $a_2=a_1\cdot p_{\alpha}$. Otherwise, the quotient contributes no primes to the count of distinct prime numbers. Continue in this fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a graph where there is a vertex for each of the numbers $a_1,\dotsc,a_n$, and an edge joining vertices $a_i$ and $a_j$ if and only if the ratio $a_i/a_j$ is a prime. Label each edge with that prime number.

For each prime number that appears as the label on more than one edge, erase all but one of the edges for which that prime is the label. This will not decrease the total number of distinct primes appearing, but it will assure that all the primes appearing are distinct.

Now I claim that there can be no cycles in the resulting graph. For, if you travel around a cycle from some vertex $a_i$ back to itself, along the way you would have multiplied by some primes and divided by some primes, and wound up with the same number you started with, so, by the Unique Factorization Theorem, each prime labelling an edge in the cycle must appear (at least) twice in the cycle, contradicting our construction which ensured each prime appears only once.

But a graph on $n$ vertices with no cycles is a forest (a collection of trees), so it has at most $n-1$ edges, so we have at most $n-1$ distinct primes. QED.

Oh, and I suppose this is a "number theory solution", since it relies upon the Unique Factorization Theorem.

Answer (score -1):

Assume $n$ numbers with at least $n$ distinct primes as quotients. Let $p$ be one of those primes, so we have two numbers $x$ and $px$. Remove all prime factors $p$ from all numbers except the one $p$ in $px$; this doesn’t remove any unique prime quotients but may create more, so we have still at least $n$ unique prime quotients with $px$ being the only number with the prime factor $p$.

Since $px$ is the only number with a prime factor $p$, $a/px$ or $px/a$ is only a prime if $a = x$, so removing $px$ removes exactly one distinct prime quotient, leaving $n-1$ integers with at least $n-1$ distinct prime quotients. We repeat until we have two integers with two distinct prime quotients which is not possible.

Oh well. I suppose that went right over someone’s head.